# Regex - how to extract integers only not float from text

Tags: java, regex

Given a text:

`Why should the number 12.8 be rounded to 13. It must be rather 11`

What must be a regex to extract, the integer values only:

```
13
11
```

I tried this: `\d+(?!\\.)`

But still no luck.

Comment: A hint: use both negative lookbehind and lookahead and word boundaries.

Comment: @VinceEmigh - I tried multiple options but no luck. I am new to regex and have basic understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use lookarounds (lookbehind, lookahead) to check what happens before and after the digits you match:

a naive approach:

```
(?<![0-9]|[0-9]\.)[0-9]+(?!\.?[0-9])
```

an efficient approach:

```
[0-9](?<![0-9][0-9]|[0-9]\.[0-9])[0-9]*+(?!\.[0-9])
```

*(Because this one quickly discards positions where there is not a digit)*

Note: don't forget to escape the backslashes in the java string.

You can also write it like this:

```
\b[0-9](?<![0-9]\.[0-9])[0-9]*+(?!\.[0-9])
```

Comment: this works!!!!!! thank you too much..
I used the naive approach... If you don't mind, can you elucidate this to me? 
I will post this answer to my question above.

Comment: @Casimir, can you explain the `(?<![0-9]|[0-9]\.)` ? Specifically, why `[0-9]|[0-9]` is needed? (i know how a negate lookahead assertion works, but didn't understand your solution)

Comment: @BrunoNegrãoZica: the goal is to avoid a digit, or a digit and a dot before the digits you want to match. `(?<!...)` is the lookbehind and means *"not preceded with"*

Comment: @BrunoNegrãoZica: Perhaps you didn't understand this point: most of the time variable length lookbehinds aren't supported by regex engines. But the java regex engine supports limited variable length lookbehinds like `(?<=.{0,1000})` but also several fixed alternatives like `(?<=ab|abc|abcd)`

Comment: @RaviTejwani: The first approach starts with a lookbehind that contains an alternation, this means that the two branches of the alternations must be tested for each positions in the string before to try the end of the pattern if one of the two succeeds. The second approach reduces the number of tests since it begins with a digit. For example if at a position in the string there's a letter, no need to test the two branches of the lookbehind, `[0-9]` makes the pattern fail immediately *(the regex engine walks from left to right and tests all the positions in the string)*.

Comment: @RaviTejwani: more informations (and explanations) in the book: *Mastering regular expressions - Jeff Friedl, ed. O'Reilly*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I read about lookahead and lookbehind after looking at your answer and now I understand it better. 

I tried this: (?<![0-9]\\.?)[0-9]+(?!\\.?[0-9]) in my matcher and it works too? Any suggestions

Comment: @RaviTejwani: You are probably right, the java regex engine seems to be smart enough to see that `(?<![0-9]\.?)` has a limited variable length. *(Note that it isn't evident at all since this part of the java regex engine is full of bugs, there's a topic on SO about how you can dupe the java regex engine when it checks if a lookbehind has a limited variable length or not)*

Comment: @RaviTejwani: Note that `[0-9]++(?!\.[0-9])` is better than `[0-9]+(?!\.?[0-9])` since it avoids backtracking and the optional dot.

Comment: I still don't understand (?<![0-9]|[0-9]\.). I undestand the [0-9]\., which means: don't accept a digit preceded by "a digit and a dot", like 2.8. But i don't understand the first part [0-9]| (before the pipe). I understand that as "don't accept a digit that is preceded by a digit". Which would deny 13, because  3 is preceded by 1... ??

Comment: @BrunoNegrãoZica: take `26.13` as example string, if you write only `(?<![0-9]\.)[0-9]+(?!\.?[0-9])`, "3" becomes a possible match, but it you write `(?<![0-9]|[0-9]\.)[0-9]+(?!\.?[0-9])`, "3" fails too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved applying two regex. The command line bellow shows how they work:

```
echo "Why number 12.8 be rounded to 13. It must be rather 11" | grep -Po '\b\d+\.?\d\b' | grep -Po '^\d+$'
```

The first regex select all numbers, including floating points. The second regex selects only integers.

**In java**, use `"\\b\\d+\\.?\\d\\b"` to select all numbers, and `"^\\d+$"` to select only integers.

Comment: the approach will work in java, just need to use the \\ doble backslashes

Comment: So, explain it on your answer.Given that the OP said `I am new to regex and have basic understanding` :) it will help for sure.

Comment: @BrunoNegrãoZica - Thanks for your response. I intend to user Pattern Matcher in Java and was hoping if there is a way, we could define one pattern or regex ?